# Rolls fall flat

Tags: yeast, rising, proofing

when making yeast rolls mine will rise the first time then not at all the second time most occasions, I read about over rising first round, so I think this could be my problem, however when I do get them to rise the second time they seem to fall flat in the oven, or when I pull the cover off to place in oven they fall flat, any advice on how to fix this.

Comment: You will have to post your complete recipe and process here. We cannot know what went wrong if we don't know what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your proving environment is maintaining temperature.   If you are making the dough with blood temperature water then the residual heat in the dough will get the yeast going but when it cools down the yeast may cease to be active.    The dough should double in size on the first prove.   Also make sure your flour is proper strong flour and that the dough is being worked enough.  Even strong flour won't achieve the correct elasticity if it isn't worked enough so when the yeast gives off its CO2  the dough won't prove correctly.  When doing second prove don't let them go all the way as they will still prove some in the oven before the crust forms.

Comment: LOL - I've never heard it referred to as "blood temperature" before! Very descriptive :)

Comment: Yes haha blood temp is actually the correct term. It's the perfect temperature for yeast as it is actually a living organism.  That's why I always sneer at dem vegan types who will go to a restaurant and order a pizza with no cheese,   thinking is an animal free product.

Comment: I disagree with this troubleshooting. First, using AP flour instead of strong flour will not prevent rising, it will just produce a well risen bread with a different texture. Second, using colder dough will slow down rising, but not prevent it, and it will make much tastier bread than when rising at blood temperature, at which the yeast is indeed very active and produces lots of ammonia and thioles. The yeast is active even as low as fridge temperatures (only its first contact with water should be room temp), and using less than body temp won't produce the problems from the question.